# Truncating text not working directly within flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a javascript ui component that creates a stacked list of buttons (actually a **ul > li** structure). The component is used in a reporting software, where the user can set the size of the container that the button sits in and it can have any number of buttons. The buttons then need to fill the space set by the user. Text needs to be centered vertically and horizontally. I've used flexbox on the **ul** to control the layout of the buttons, and then again on the **li** elements to center the text vertically and horizontally. However, if the text is too long for the button it clips and does not truncate.

Without changing the markup, is it possible to achieve this with CSS?

**Edit**
One further requirement is the text needs to truncate with ellipsis(...) not wrap. If a button contains one very long word wrapping does not solve the issue. I've updated the codepen with such an example.

Html:

```
<div class="reportContainer">
  <ul class="segMBtn">
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">North</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">East</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">South</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">West</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">Something else really long that should truncate but doesn't want to truncate even though it should</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

LESS/CSS:

```
.reportContainer {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  margin:3rem;
}

.segMBtn {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.segMBtn__btn {
  display:flex;
  border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:0 1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;

  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;

  &:hover {
    background:#ececec;
  }

  &:active {
    background:#cdcdcd;
  }

  &:first-child {
    border-top:none;
  }
}
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/tjkrumm/pen/jAkZVa

Answer (score 0):

In class .segMBtn__btn remove `white-space:nowrap;`

```css
.reportContainer {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  margin:3rem;
}

.segMBtn {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.segMBtn__btn {
  display:flex;
  border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:0 1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;

  &:hover {
    background:#ececec;
  }
  
  &:active {
    background:#cdcdcd;
  }
  
  &:first-child {
    border-top:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="reportContainer">
  <ul class="segMBtn">
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">North</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">East</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">South</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">West</li>
    <li class="segMBtn__btn">Something else really long that should truncate but doesn't want to truncate even though it should</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Ram, the text needs to truncate with ellipsis not wrap. For instance if the last box was one very long word without spaces this solution would still clip.

Comment: add to the class word-wrap:break-word;  display:inline;

Comment: Unfortunately that prevents the text from centering vertically.

Comment: you can add padding-top:20px; to that and it should solve it :)

Comment: Thanks @Ram, as I mentioned though the buttons are of dynamic size, so a hardcoded value of 20px only solves this particular example.